# Visual Studio - Can I view the code of an older version of a project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I made the mistake of changing a subroutine in a project and publishing it.  Now I want to revert back to the older subroutine.  Is it possible to find the older project and retrieve the older subroutine?

Comment: start using source control

Comment: You're looking for source control.

Comment: for example, Team Foundation Server

Comment: Git is a good option as well

Comment: ok, then the answer is yes? does that mean it is available in source control or Team Foundation Server?  When I go there there is no server.

Comment: ... You are on your own at that point. SVN is old. But easy to use (use source control... always)

Comment: So is the answer no? If source control (don't know anything about it) is not used then the older versions are gone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Team Foundation Server can do this for you. You can now be set up without any hassle on your developement machine. The integration in the VS Team Explorer is seamless. Very easy to handle. See this guide for working with source control projects
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181384.aspx

Even easier and not so much overhead on your machine: sign up for Visual Studio Online (free for a 5 user team). The cloud source control is set  up in minutes. If you are not against saving your data in the cloud give it a try.
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/what-is-visual-studio-online-vs.aspx

[image: Visual Studio Online]

The alternatives (SVN, GIT) are also very good (consider reading about the difference of central and decentral source control) but need a little more knowledge and a good workflow.

If you happen to have lost changes before installing version control there's nothing you can do in visual studio. You can try a restore on file level (the option would be previous versions in the windows explorer)
as source code is plain text. There`s a "previous version" mechanism of windows explorer! Just go to the properties of your project folder
[image: Previous files in explorer]

Note: previous version / shadow copying must have been enabled before or else the tab will be blank.

Comment: Good answer! But for those unfamiliar with source control, note that these tools help prevent losing old versions of your code. Installing them afterwards won't help you recover lost code.

Comment: Thanks Marc Wittmann and @A.Franklin. I appear to be without hope ;-p

Comment: That`s right... it only recovers what has been saved/versioned before. A good start for beginners would be this introduction
http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/intro-to-version-control.html

Comment: Can I engage the Source Control on this old project now in order to provide older versions or do you have to engage it at the very beginning of the project creation?

Comment: You need to install source control first (see link in the comment for basic information). But see my edited post for a file level recovery.. if you enabled previous versions in windows you may be lucky.

Comment: Thanks for the extended information!  A glimmer of hope returned until I went to the project folder / Properties and found "There are no previous versions available"!  I contacted our IT dept and they looked into my computer and found that everything needed was disabled! ...oh well.  I'm having them get it all enabled.  Thanks for your help @Marc Wittmann.

Comment: No problem.. sorry for you. Now there`s nothing more you can do.. better enable to previous version function in windows now  and source control to be sure in the future you won`t have the trouble again

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible unless you have stored your code in source control. It sounds like you have not yet done this, so I suggest using this is a (harsh) lesson and make the next move the one to install some kind of SCM.

You can signup for a free version of TFS online from microsoft the will integrate directly into Visual Studio. That will allow you to instantly check in changes and view the history of files and in this case, get a previous version of a file.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/what-is-visual-studio-online-vs.aspx

Comment: Thanks @ChrisBint.  Yes, this is a harsh lesson! Can I start SCM on this already existing project.  Or, do you have to do that at the beginning when you create the project?

Comment: @BobT, you should be able to add a project to source control at any point, though I'd have the code compiling without error first if possible. Sorry for your loss; it always sucks to lose work!